# Extract particular position from all tuples in dictionary keys

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-structures, map-function

From a dictionary whose keys are (x, y) pairs, I would like to get the list of all x's and the list of all y's.

This is how my dictionary looks:

```
(x, y) : value

{(17, 19): 1, (22, 24): 0, (18, 24): 1}
```

The goal is:

```
x={17,22,18} and y={19,24,24}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a dictionary and to get keys in separate lists, you can use list comprehension

```
d ={(17, 19): 1, (22, 24): 0, (18, 24): 1}

x = [i[0] for i in d.keys()]
y = [i[1] for i in d.keys()]

x
[17, 22, 18]

y
[19, 24, 24]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
d ={(17, 19): 1, (22, 24): 0, (18, 24): 1}
x,y = zip(*d)
x,y
```

Output:

```
((17, 22, 18), (19, 24, 24))
```

Solution Without using zip:

```
x = [ i[0] for i in d ]
y = [ i[1] for i in d ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Is there any other way to do without using zip?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an interactive demonstration of one approach using destructuring assignment:

```
>>> d = {(17, 19): 1, (22, 24): 0, (18, 24): 1}
>>> k = d.keys()
>>> x = [k1 for (k1,k2) in k]
>>> x
[18, 17, 22]
>>> y = [k2 for (k1,k2) in k]
>>> y
[24, 19, 24]
>>>
```